# Intel-Based Assembly Lang. Output from stack

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, output, lifo

So at the moment my out put is:

**Area: 17 | Points: 1 | Probability: 64 / 134519798**

when it should be:

**Area: 1 | Points: 17 | Probability: 1 / 64**

The values pushed in stack goes from First to last:

64

1

17

1

So first out should be the 1 then 17...1....64. It appears as if the first 1 is being ignored so I have tried to research it to see what I can find but I am coming up short.
I have verified the the variable that I am pushing into the stack has a value.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
;
;
segment .data
display db "Area: %d | Points: %d | Probability: %d / %d",10,0
number db "", 0
;
;
segment .bss
;
radius1 resd 1 ;Radius
radius2 resd 1
radius3 resd 1
radius4 resd 1
points1 resd 1 ;Points
points2 resd 1
points3 resd 1
points4 resd 1
compArea1 resd 1 ;Computed Area
compArea2 resd 1
compArea3 resd 1
compArea4 resd 1
pie1 resd 1 ;radius*radius
pie2 resd 1
pie3 resd 1
pie4 resd 1
pb1 resd 1 ;Probability
pb2 resd 1
pb3 resd 1
pb4 resd 1
eo resd 1 ; Expected Outcome
extra resd 1
;
;
segment .text
    global  asm_main
    extern printf
asm_main:
    enter   0,0            
    pusha

    mov eax, number
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [radius1], eax

    mov eax, number
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [radius2], eax

    mov eax, number
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [radius3], eax

    mov eax, number
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [radius4], eax
    ;****************Radius End****************
    mov eax, number
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [points1], eax

    mov eax, number
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [points2], eax

    mov eax, number
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [points3], eax

    mov eax, number
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [points4], eax
    ;****************Points End****************

    mov eax, [radius1]
    imul eax, [radius1]
    mov [pie1], eax 

    mov eax, [radius2]
    imul eax, [radius2]
    mov [pie2], eax 

    mov eax, [radius3]
    imul eax, [radius3]
    mov [pie3], eax 

    mov eax, [radius4]
    imul eax, [radius4]
    mov [pie4], eax 

    ;***************Area End*******************

    mov eax, [radius1]
    mov [compArea1], eax

    mov eax, [pie2]
    sub eax, [pie1]
    mov [compArea2], eax 

    mov eax, [pie3]
    sub eax, [pie2]
    mov [compArea3], eax 

    mov eax, [pie4]
    sub eax, [pie3]
    mov [compArea4], eax 

    ;***************Computed Area Ends*********

    mov eax, [compArea1]
    imul eax, [points1]
    mov [pb1], eax

    mov eax, [compArea2]
    imul eax, [points2]
    mov [pb2], eax

    mov eax, [compArea3]
    imul eax, [points3]
    mov [pb3], eax

    mov eax, [compArea4]
    imul eax, [points4]
    mov [pb4], eax

    ;******************************************

    mov eax, [pb1]
    add eax, [pb2]
    add eax, [pb3]
    add eax, [pb4]
    mov [eo], eax

    ;***************Expected Outcome Ends******
    sub esp, 10h

    push dword [pie4]
    push dword [compArea1]
    push dword [points1]
    push dword [radius1]

    mov dword [esp], display
    call printf


    add esp, 10h


    popa
    mov     eax, 0           
    leave                     
    ret
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should copy in the entire code, including definitions, to make it more likely someone can help.

Comment: You're overwriting your last-pushed parameter with `mov dword [esp], display`!

Comment: I see... Still don't know how else I can call it out into display without overwriting. Everything I seem to try gives me a Segmentation Default

Comment: Lose the `sub esp, 10h` (why?). `push display` too. After returning from `printf`, `add esp 4 * 5` (5 parameters at 4 bytes each). Untested, but it "should" work.

Comment: Rather than `mov dword [esp], display` you need to push `display` onto the stack. Then when done, you don't subtract from the stack to clean it up, you add to it (since pushes subtract). If you push 4*5 bytes, then you need to add 4*5 to the stack, i.e., `add esp, 14h` instead of `sub esp, 10h`.

Comment: Thank you Frank it worked. However I need sub esp, 10h in  and IDK why. without it I get segmentation fault.

Comment: Please do no deface questions.